# Python beautiful soup how to get deep nested elements

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a page with the following structure:

```html
<div id ="a">
    <table>
        <td> 
            <!-- many tables and divs here -->
        </td>
        <td>
            <table></table>
            <table></table>
            <div class="tabber">
                <table></table>
                <table></table>  <!-- TARGET TABLE -->
            </div>
        </td>
    </table>
</div>
```

That's right, unfortunately no ids or classes on target or near it except "tabber".

I tried to get that div element:

```
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

stats_div = soup.findAll('div', class_ = "tabber")[1] # 1 because there are 4 elements on page with that class and number 2 is the target one
```

But it didn't work, always outputs nothing.

I tried to traverse the whole tree from the start to get the target table:

```
stats_table = soup.find(id='a').findChildren('table')[0].findChildren('td')[1].findChildren('div')[0].findChildren('table')[1]
```

But it doesn't work either. Apparently `findChildren('td')` doesn't get the first table's direct children, but instead gets all descendants. Over 100 td elements.

How do I get direct children of an element?

Is there a cleaner way to traverse such an ugly nested tree?
Why can't I select that `div` by class? It would simplify everything.

Comment: What do you mean by *it didn't work*? You'd get an *error* if there are no such divs in the page.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I get an empty list. I can get other classes just fine, but this one doesn't work. In the page the class is "tabberlive" and when I try to get it I get this: http://i.gyazo.com/ab3ceaf1f9250795456d625c7c388960.png

Comment: Then there is no such element in the resulting soup tree. There can be any number of reasons for that; the HTML served to you could simply not have that class (the server could have varied the response based on the request headers or the page is altered in the browser using scripting) or the HTML is broken and your parser didn't repair it the way your browser does (use a different parser in that case).

Comment: Would it be possible to share the actual link rather than the HTML snippet you've shown?

Comment: @OliverW. Here is the actual link http://www.soccerstats.com/team.asp?league=england&teamid=24

Comment: @Euphe, which table on that page exactly are you trying to scrape? There are three (visible) tables at the right pane under "Stats", is that it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the code you've shown seems to reflect anything on that page:

1. there is no `div` tag with an `id='a'`. In fact, there isn't a single tag with that attribute. That's why your last command `stats_table = ...` fails.
2. there are exactly 3 `div` tags with the class attribute equal to `tabber`, not 4:

   ```
   >>> len(soup.find_all('div', class_="tabber"))
   3
   ```

   And they're not empty either:

   ```
   >>> len(soup.find_all('div', class_="tabber")[1])
   7
   ```
3. There isn't a single `div` tag of the class `tabber` that has just 2 `table` children, but I assume that's because you have reduced your own example greatly.

If you want to scrape a website such as this one where you can't easily select tags by a unique `id`, then you have no choice but to help yourself with other attributes, such as the tag names. And sometimes the position of the tags compared to each other in the DOM is also a helpful technique.

For your specific problem, you could use the `title` attribute to great effect:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import urllib2
>>> url = 'http://www.soccerstats.com/team.asp?league=england&teamid=24'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), 'lxml')
>>> all_stats = soup.find('div', id='team-matches-and stats')
>>> left_column, right_column = [x for x in all_stats.table.tr.children if x.name == 'td']
>>> table1, table2 = [x for x in right_column.children if x.name == 'table']  # the two tables at the top right
>>> [x['title'] for x in right_column.find_all('div', class_='tabbertab')]
['Stats', 'Scores', 'Goal times', 'Overall', 'Home', 'Away']
```

That last part here is the interesting part: all the tables in the lower right have `title` attributes, which will allow you to select them more easy. Moreover, those attributes make the tags unique in the soup, so you can select them straight from the root:

```
>>> stats_div = soup.find('div', class_="tabbertab", title="Stats")
>>> len(stats_div.find_all('table', class_="stat"))
3
```

Those 3 items correspond to the "current streaks", "scoring" and "home/away advantage" subitems.